# Angular-UI-Select ng-model not working with a simple variable on $scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ui-select

### How do you clear an array with selected values so that values can return to the select?

I have a people array. The people array values are available in select. When I choose names, they are transferred to the `multipleDemo` array. And you can not reselect them from select because they disappear and are moved to the `multipleDemo`  array. With the Delete button I have to delete all elements from the `multipleDemo` array (except the first element) into the people array. So that you can again choose a name from the select. Error in function `$clearTag`.

Expecting behavior:
Example:

1. Select: Wladimir
2. Appear tag Wladimir
3. Select Wladimir (You can't choose Wladimir because he is already chosen)
4. Click Delete. Cut elements(tags) with multipleDemo array and put them in array people
5. You can again select Wladimir

Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/TPZjXkkSRrIc5ApzP07F?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- ui-select files -->
  <script src="select.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="select.css">

  <script src="demo.js"></script>

  <!-- Select2 theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.default.css">

  <style>
    body {
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .select2 > .select2-choice.ui-select-match {
      /* Because of the inclusion of Bootstrap */
      height: 29px;
    }

    .selectize-control > .selectize-dropdown {
      top: 36px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

```html
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    
  <h3>Array of strings</h3>
  <button ng-click='clearTag()'>Delete</button>
  <ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="multipleDemo" 
  on-select="OnClickSelect($item)" on-remove="OnRemoveSelect($item)"
  theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select name...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices  repeat="item in people | filter:$select.search">
      {{item.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo}}</p>
  <hr>  

</body>
</html>
```

**demo.js**

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.multipleDemo =[];
    $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'Colombia' }
  ];

  $scope.OnClickSelect=function(item)
  {
   $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.name);
  }
  
  $scope.OnRemoveSelect = function(item) { 
   var index = $scope.people.indexOf(item.name);
   $scope.people.splice(index, 1); 
  }
  
  $scope.clearTag = function() {
    for(var i =0; i < $scope.multipleDemo.length; i++) {
      $scope.multipleDemo.splice($scope.multipleDemo[i], 1000);
      $scope.people.push($scope.multipleDemo[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the behavior you are expecting. By the way your **clearTag** function won't be called because you declare it as *$scope* in js but call it *$ctrl* in html

Comment: Function clearTag. Cut out elements using the splice method wants to put back in the people array

Comment: You should read up on how the [`ngController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) directive works. You either inject `$scope` into your controller, as you've shown, and access scope variables without an object reference, or you use something like `ng-controller="controller as $ctrl"` and use the `$ctrl.clearTag()` syntax. You're currently trying to use both. You likely have errors in your console regarding that; if you'd like further help, please show those in your question.

Comment: I deleted $ctrl. I have ng-click="clearTag()". I don't have in console any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Angular-UI-Select Common Issues

### `ng-model` not working with a simple variable on `$scope`

You cannot write:

> WRONG
>
> ```
> <ui-select ng-model="multipleDemo"> <!-- Wrong -->
>   [...]
> </ui-select>
> ```

You need to write[:](http://plnkr.co/edit/ubjKY3APHhvf8zF9MtR8?p=preview)

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.multipleDemo"> <!-- Correct -->
  [...]
</ui-select>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularUI-Select FAQ - Common Issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/FAQs#common-issues)

---

### Update

> `vm.multipleDemo` doesn't work; I try `$parent.multipleDemo` - it works. I don't understand `$parent`. Why it works?

For `vm.multipleDemo` to work, the controller must initialize the `vm` object:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.vm = { multipleDemo: [] };
```

> New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the [data hiding] problem often shows up when these directives are involved. (See [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZfUQN?p=preview) for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.
>
> — [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14049480/5535245)

Avoid using `$parent` to fix a data hiding problem. It is a brittle solution as there can be more than one level of scope heirarchy between the controller and the `ui-select` directive. I consider the use of `$parent` to be a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem.

---

### Update #2

> When I can use `$ctrl` in view and `this` in controller?

If the controller is instantiated with "controller as" syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl as $ctrl">

    <ui-select ng-model="$ctrl.multipleDemo">
       <!-- -->
    </ui-select>
```

Then there is no need to use `$scope`:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {
    this.multipleDemo =  [];
```

And it avoids the data hiding problem.

For more information, see

- ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11605917/5535245)

Comment: vm.multipleDemo doesn't work; I try $parent.multipleDemo - it works. I don't understand $parent. Why it works?

Comment: When I can use '$ctrl' in view and 'this' in controller?

Comment: Is it possible to iterate over the array, excluding the first element (omit the first element in the array)?

Comment: That should be asked as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).